# Css customization inside Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

What I am wondering is if I can edit the ID tags/Class names of different sites web parts so that they are unique enough to be identified from a single Master Css file.

I am wondering if this is possible so I can centralize where to house the Css

Then based off of if that is possible, the next question would be HOW to do that, I can F12 to bring up the HTML, look through the code, and even do a temp edit to show differences, but how do I edit this and keep the changes without destroying the rest of its function?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the recommended ways to modify branding in SharePoint online.

1. By creating custom themes
2. By creating custom cascading style sheets (CSS)

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/sharepoint-site-branding-and-page-customization-solutions